# Changing date format in CSV file using Ubuntu bash/awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have csv files where date is in wrong format. Incoming format is e.g. 15.11.2015 and I should change is to %Y-%m-%d (2015-11-15). I've tried to create an bash/awk script to where I change this value which is in column 43. First row is a header. So far I've managed to create a script which finds the value and replaces it with front slashes:

```
awk -v FS=";" 'NR>1{split($43,a,".");$43=a[2]"/"a[1]"/"a[3]}1' OFS=";" fileIn
```

I've tried to change the format with date command but I haven't found a way to use it in awk script. This would print the date in right format:

```
 date -d 11/25/2015 +%Y-%m-%d
```

EDIT. I need to change the format, otherwise the leading zeros are missed if date or month is < 10.

Comment: I don't understand, why not jsut change the `/` for `-` in the awk command ?

Comment: If the date or month is < 10, leading zeros are missed.

Comment: What? Please show an example in your question.

Comment: Incoming date is 1.2.2016, so the converted date would be 2016-2-1.

Comment: Use sprintf and pad it.

Comment: Thanks a lot 123, this was a lot simpler than I thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed 123's advice and used sprintf and padding and my working solution is now:

```
awk -v FS=";" 'NR>1{split($43,a,".");$43=sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d",a[3],a[2],a[1])}1' OFS=";" fileIn
```

EDIT. Cleaned after 123's comment.

Comment: You can use a single sprintf. `$43=sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d",a[3],a[2],a[1])`